# Mouse selection in Eclipse always selects text before the cursor

Tags: eclipse

This may be an already answered question but an hour searching has not revealed any solution. In other IDE's, I typically delete a line by placing my mouse cursor at the end of the previous line and then drag the cursor to the end of the next line (or end of the block of code I want to delete).  I then hit delete and it saves me the trouble of having backspace to bring the code following up to fill the space left over from the deletion.

For some reason in Eclipse, when I do this, it wants to also select the current line that the cursor is on (in addition to selecting what I am trying to delete). SO if I am not careful, I end up deleting a line of code I didn't want to remove. I only want to remove from the cursor forward to the end of the selection.

Does anyone know how to fix this. I am new to Eclipse (having previously used INtelliJ) and this is a real annoyance to me while developing.

I've tried looking in all the editor settings and looking online for different solutions but no luck so far.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of Eclipse? What operating system?

Comment: Windows 11.  Eclipse Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
Build id: 20230608-1333

Comment: In which editor? Have you added any other plug-ins that what it came with?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Plugins:
Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0 (I believe this came with because I did not add it)
Eclipse m2E - Maven Support
Eclipse Marketplace Client 1.10.0  (I believe this came with because I did not add it)
EGit - Git INtegration for Eclipse 6.0.0 (I believe this came with because I did not add it)
Sprint Tools Suite 4 4.19.0 Release (I did add this)

Comment: When I asked which editor, it meant what kind of file were you editing, and in what editor inside Eclipse was it opened (check the file's context menu's Open With submenu). Which one's misbehaving?

Comment: I tried different editors, but I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2023-06 on Windows 11. Maybe you bound the _Delete to End of Line_ command to the _Delete_ key.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am using the Java Editor on a Java file. I feel like this is almost certainly some dumb setting in Eclipse, but it is not apparent what that would be from looking over all the preferences for editors (including the Java editor)

Comment: What key binding do you have in the preferences _General > Keys_ for the command _Delete to End of Line_? Try a fresh workspace, to find out whether it's related to the preferences. What do you get with right-click _Open With > Text Editor_?

Comment: Delete To End oF Line Key is not assigned. This is a mouse related action anyway.  Opening with TextEditor gives the same result.. Opened new project in a different workspace and same result.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. You said "then hit delete" which contradicts "This is a mouse related action anyway." Does it make a difference when you select the text using the keyboard? Please show before vs. via mouse vs. via keyboard. Please improve your question which is unclear without all the comments.